# How to make Ruby Modules Dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have four models, `User`, `Profile`, `Badge`, and `Membership`,
that have almost identical `previous` and `next` methods.  The following example is from my `User` model.

```
def next
  self.class.find :first, 
                  :conditions => [ "created_at > ? AND user_id = ?",
                                   self.created_at, self.user_id ], 
                  :order => "created_at ASC"
end

def previous
  self.class.find :first, 
                  :conditions => [ "created_at < ? AND user_id = ?",
                                   self.created_at, self.user_id ], 
                  :order => "created_at DESC"
end
```

Instead of having the essentially same methods repeated four times once for each model, I'm attempting to put these methods into an external module `Extensions::Utility` so that each model can `include Extensions::Utility`.

What is the best way to implement this method so that it supports dynamic substitution of `user` for other models?

My environment is Ruby/Rails 3.0.6.

Comment: Do the column names like user_id always correspond to the model names like User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilo's answer has a point. I changed the method `next` to `nekst`.

```
module Extensions
  module Utility
    def id; "#{self.class.downcase}_id" end

    def nekst
      self.class.find :first, 
                      :conditions => [ "created_at > ? AND #{id} = ?",
                                       self.created_at, self.send(id) ], 
                      :order => "created_at ASC"
    end

    def previous
      self.class.find :first, 
                      :conditions => [ "created_at < ? AND #{id} = ?",
                                       self.created_at, self.send(id) ], 
                      :order => "created_at DESC"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good solution, but `nekst` is a terrible method name. :)

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that "next" is a keyword in the Ruby language!!

I would recommend not to define any methods with names that are part of the Ruby language..

Comment: Good point.  Renaming them to 'preceding/succeeding' is probably the best route.